# Problem to access MySQL table using WildFly 27 as Server

Tags: java, mysql, wildfly-27

I'm trying to access my mysql table but nothing happen. I've Wildfly 27 as server I don't any type error that say how to solve this.

Result of deployment:

```
12:25:52,674 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (External Management Request Threads -- 3) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location C:\Users\Ilo Gabriel\eclipse-workspace\wildfly-27.0.1.Final\standalone\data\content\f8\9e6dc021fddf0cb47a1546bafd2abef63ad4fa\content
12:25:56,980 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 357) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: '/itcmedbr' from server 'default-server'
12:26:10,869 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 368) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU'
12:26:12,013 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.beans] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 368) HHH10005004: Stopping BeanContainer : org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.CdiBeanContainerExtendedAccessImpl@504ca935
12:26:13,196 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 368) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU'
12:26:24,518 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment itcmedbr.war (runtime-name: itcmedbr.war) in 29132ms
12:26:25,045 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "itcmedbr.war" (runtime-name: "itcmedbr.war")
12:27:29,234 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for itcmedbr_PU
12:27:33,219 INFO  [org.jipijapa] (MSC service thread 1-8) JIPIORMV6020260: Second level cache enabled for itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU
12:27:40,142 INFO  [org.infinispan.CONTAINER] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 368) ISPN000556: Starting user marshaller 'org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.marshalling.jboss.JBossMarshaller'
12:27:43,345 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 368) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU'
12:27:43,388 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 368) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: itcmedbr_PU]
12:27:44,235 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment itcmedbr.war
12:27:44,310 WARN  [org.hibernate.orm.deprecation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 368) HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
12:27:49,603 WARN  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.opentracing] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYTRACEXT0012: No Jaeger endpoint or sender-binding configured. Installing a no-op sender
12:27:50,027 INFO  [io.jaegertracing.internal.JaegerTracer] (MSC service thread 1-1) No shutdown hook registered: Please call close() manually on application shutdown.
12:27:50,031 INFO  [org.wildfly.microprofile.opentracing.smallrye] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYTRAC0001: Tracer initialized: JaegerTracer(version=Java-1.6.0, serviceName=itcmedbr.war, reporter=RemoteReporter(sender=NoopSender(), closeEnqueueTimeout=1000), sampler=ConstSampler(decision=true, tags={sampler.type=const, sampler.param=true}), tags={hostname=DESKTOP-MOJECP9, jaeger.version=Java-1.6.0, ip=192.168.100.128}, zipkinSharedRpcSpan=false, expandExceptionLogs=false, useTraceId128Bit=false)
12:27:50,571 INFO  [org.jipijapa] (MSC service thread 1-1) JIPIORMV6020260: Second level cache enabled for itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU
12:27:53,256 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 368) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'itcmedbr.war#itcmedbr_PU'
12:27:58,228 INFO  [SQL dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 368) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
12:27:58,469 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 368) Envers integration enabled? : true
12:28:13,467 INFO  [jakarta.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.faces.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 374) Inicializando Mojarra 4.0.0.SP01 para o contexto '/itcmedbr'
12:28:16,760 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 374) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/itcmedbr' for server 'default-server'
12:28:19,771 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 3) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "itcmedbr.war" with deployment "itcmedbr.war"
12:28:19,876 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (External Management Request Threads -- 3) WFLYDR0002: Content removed from location C:\Users\Ilo Gabriel\eclipse-workspace\wildfly-27.0.1.Final\standalone\data\content\4b\8235b8df8a07215e3d92a6db457afc96d062f5\content
```

My datasource in standalone.xml:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_medical</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>root</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                </datasource>
```

driver:

```
<driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
      <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
      <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
</driver>
```

I configured my datasource by HAL Management Console.
persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                                 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="itcmedbr_PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>      
      <!-- Configurações específicas do Hibernate -->
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Method to read data in MySQL:

```
public Usuarios_DAO_W1 getLoginW1(String Nome, String Senha, String CNPJ) throws Exception
    {
        String ListarLogin = "SELECT * " + 
                "FROM Tabela_Profissional_Medico WHERE Apelido = ? " +
                "AND Senha = ? AND CNPJ = ?";
        
        Connection conectar = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        System.out.println("PacientesDAO chamando conectar DB...");
        System.out.println("Nome: " + Nome);
        
        pstm = conectar.prepareStatement(ListarLogin);
        
        pstm.setString(1, Nome);
        pstm.setString(2, Senha);
        pstm.setString(3, CNPJ);
        
        rs = pstm.executeQuery();
        
        Usuarios_DAO_W1 constpaciente = new Usuarios_DAO_W1();
        
        if (rs.next())                
        {            
            constpaciente.setNome(rs.getString("Nome"));
            constpaciente.setApelido(rs.getString("Apelido"));
            constpaciente.setCoren(rs.getString("Coren"));
            constpaciente.setCremerj(rs.getString("Cremerj"));
            constpaciente.setSenha(rs.getString("Senha"));
            constpaciente.setTipo(rs.getString("Tipo"));
                
        }else
        {   
            System.out.println("Senha invalida....");
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<br>");
            out.println("<h1>PacientesDAO - Usuário ou senha invalido!</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
            out.close();
        }
        
        return constpaciente;
    }
```

I must to say that this is my first time that I use wildfly server to read mysql data.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?